# Maintain zip file structure

Tags: unix, zip

I have a directory

```
main_folder
  first_folder
    second_folder
      empty.txt
      another_folder
        another_empty.txt
```

I want to zip `second_folder`, and I'm in `main_folder`, so I zipped with the command

```
zip -jr first_folder/zip_file first_folder/second_folder
```

The zip file contains

```
empty.txt
another_empty.txt
```

But I want

```
empty.txt
another_folder
  another_empty.txt
```

How can I have that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -j (junk paths) flag you set is killing what you want since it strips out the folder paths.  That being said, however, I don't really see a way to just do second+.
From the Man Page:

> You  may  want  to  make  a zip archive that contains the files in foo,
>      without recording the directory name, foo.  You can use the  -j  option
>     to leave off the paths, as in:
>     zip -j foo foo/*

From what I can tell, that is just how it works in "zip" (nothing in the man suggests otherwise).

**Edit:** I was a bit after the other guy as I was trying to find out how to do what you want.

Why don't you just navigate to the directory and zip it?  If you want to end up back where you were, this will do it (although a waste of time imo).

> cd first_folder/second_folder/ && zip -r name ./ && mv name.zip ${here} && cd -

(Thanks to @KarthikT for the "cd -" shortcut).

Comment: The `-j` option is there because I don't want the Zip stores the full path. I want it to only store starting with the files in `second_folder`. I think your suggestion about navigating to the directory works. Is there a way to do it without navigating?

Comment: @nerdwaller  you can just do `cd -` to get to old pwd

Comment: @KarthikT That's assuming you're starting at ~/ though...

Comment: Yeah, but the -j option is what removes the file path, so you could have one item in each of 15 folders deep, and on extraction you would have 15 items in the one directory...  I don't see one without navigating at this point.

Comment: @nerdwaller i think you are missunderstanding `cd ` and `cd -` here. `cd -` returns you to your here variable exactly

Comment: @KarthikT You're right, I didn't realize that if you set the var that worked (I tested it without the var set).  Sorry for doubting you, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @nerdwaller im sorry,but there is still some miss understanding. `cd -` will work without your `here = $(pwd)` what i meant was that cd internally does that already, so if you do `cd abc` cd records your old pwd ( env var $OLDPWD) before doing `cd` so that the next `cd -` basically works as `cd $OLDPWD`

Comment: Guess I am struggling this evening.  Haha, I always learn something new with Linux I never knew.  What a fantastic OS.  **Edit:** Fixed above.  Thanks again, I get it now.  The most recent folder you were directly in is "cd -"

Comment: yup very elegant behavior, came across it very recently myself

Answer (score 1):

From [man page for zip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip)

`-j
--junk-paths
Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do not store directory names. By default, zip will store the full path (relative to the current directory).`

Just removing the -j should fix it.

Comment: Well, but then the Zip stores the **full path**. I want it to only store starting with the files in `second_folder`.

Comment: yes i figured it was something like that.. y not `cd ..../second_folder && zip -r * && cd -` :) let me see if any more elegant option is present

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710482/how-to-create-a-zip-file-without-entire-directory-structure) i think indicates that there is no other option..